# How is box-shadow returned in IE9?

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, css

I need to know how the CSS `box-shadow` property is returned in IE9 when using jQuery's `.css('box-shadow')`. However, I can't install IE9 on my computer. Can someone run [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FY6Ap/1/) in IE9 and tell me what the result is?

Comment: Next time, you can try http://browserstack.com/ (live interaction) or http://browsershots.org/ (a static screenshot) to see what happens. Or just set up a VM with the desired browser stack (I've written a detailed guide and posted it on SO, see my profile).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is what you were looking for?

[image: Result of Drop-Shadow IE9]